# using enumeratum enum as BSONDocument value does not compile

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

when I try to wrap my query in BSONDocument and putting my enumeratum enum as the value it docent compile.

for example, my enum:

```
sealed trait ProcessingStatus extends EnumEntry with UpperSnakecase

object ProcessingStatus extends Enum[ProcessingStatus] with ReactiveMongoBsonEnum[ProcessingStatus] {

  val values: IndexedSeq[ProcessingStatus] = findValues

  case object Processing extends ProcessingStatus

  case object Done extends ProcessingStatus

}
```

and I have play json serializer that explains how to serialize:

```
object JsonSerialization {

  import reactivemongo.api.bson._

  implicit object ProcessingStatusReader extends BSONReader[ProcessingStatus] {
    override def readTry(bson: BSONValue): Try[ProcessingStatus] = bson match {
      case BSONString(s) => bson.asTry[ProcessingStatus]
      case _ => Failure(new RuntimeException("String value expected"))
    }
  }

  implicit object ProcessingStatusWriter extends BSONWriter[ProcessingStatus] {
    override def writeTry(t: ProcessingStatus): Try[BSONString] = Try(BSONString(t.entryName))
  }
  //Report Serializers
  implicit val ProcessingStatusFormat: Format[ProcessingStatus] = EnumFormats.formats(ProcessingStatus)
  implicit val ReportFormat: OFormat[Report] = Json.format[Report]
}
```

and now in my dao this does not compile:

```
import reactivemongo.play.json.compat.json2bson.{toDocumentReader, toDocumentWriter}
import serializers.JsonSerialization._

    def findReport(reportId: String) = {
      val test = BSONDocument("123" -> ProcessingStatus.Processing) // dosent compile
    }
```

screenshot:

[image]

compilation error:

```
overloaded method apply with alternatives:
  (elms: Iterable[(String, reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONValue)])reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONDocument <and>
  (elms: reactivemongo.api.bson.ElementProducer*)reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONDocument
 cannot be applied to ((String, enums.ProcessingStatus.Done.type))
    val test = BSONDocument("status" -> ProcessingStatus.Done)
```

Comment: How could it work? `JsonSerialization` doesn't provide `BSONWriter[ProcessingStatus.Processing]`, neither `{toDocumentReader, toDocumentWriter}` that only work with `BSONDocument`/`OFormat` (and not `Format`).

Comment: @cchantep edited JsonSerialization (as you can see in the question as well) my BSONWriter/BSONReader, still docent work. its is hard to find the right example,,,

Comment: "It doesn't work" is far from being sufficiently specific. To get help about an error, paste the error details.

Comment: @cchantep I wrote in the question that BSONDocument does not compile, I don't know how else to describe it, I added a screenshot if it will help.

Answer (score 0):

An IDE error is not a compilation error (recommend to use `sbt` and its console to tests).

Your code (simplified as bellow), is compiling fine, whatever is telling the IDE (which is wrong).

```scala
import reactivemongo.api.bson._
import scala.util.Try

trait ProcessingStatus {
  def entryName = "foo"
}

object JsonSerialization {
  implicit object ProcessingStatusWriter extends BSONWriter[ProcessingStatus] {
    override def writeTry(t: ProcessingStatus): Try[BSONString] = Try(BSONString(t.entryName))
  }
}

import JsonSerialization._

BSON.write(new ProcessingStatus {})
```

> *Note.1:* `writeTry` doesn't override anything, so the modifier is useless (and can lead to missunderstanding).

> *Note.2:* `Try(..)` with a pure value such as `BSONString(t.entryName)` is over-engineered, rather use `Success(..)`.

> *Note.3:* Convenient factories are available such as `val w = BSONWriter[T] { t => ... }`.

---

*Edit:*

The typeclass `BSONWriter` (as most typeclass) is invariant, so having a `BSONWriter[T]` in the implicit scope doesn't allow to resolve a `BSONWriter[U] forSome { U <: T }`.

```scala
trait ProcessingStatus {
  def entryName: String
}

object ProcessingStatus {
  case object Done extends ProcessingStatus { val entryName = "done" }
}

object JsonSerialization {
  implicit object ProcessingStatusWriter extends BSONWriter[ProcessingStatus] {
    override def writeTry(t: ProcessingStatus): Try[BSONString] = Try(BSONString(t.entryName))
  }
}

import JsonSerialization._

BSON.write(ProcessingStatus.Done
/*
<console>:32: error: could not find implicit value for parameter writer: reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONWriter[ProcessingStatus.Done.type]
       BSON.write(ProcessingStatus.Done)
 */

// --- BUT ---

BSON.write(ProcessingStatus.Done: ProcessingStatus)
// Success(BSONString(done))
```

Also exposing `Done` (and other cases) as `ProcessingStatus` in the API is working.

```scala
import reactivemongo.api.bson._
import scala.util.Try

sealed trait ProcessingStatus {
  def entryName: String
}

object ProcessingStatus {
  val Done: ProcessingStatus = new ProcessingStatus { val entryName = "done" }
}

object JsonSerialization {
  implicit object ProcessingStatusWriter extends BSONWriter[ProcessingStatus] {
    override def writeTry(t: ProcessingStatus): Try[BSONString] = Try(BSONString(t.entryName))
  }
}

import JsonSerialization._

BSON.write(ProcessingStatus.Done)
```

Comment: added the compilation error in the end of the question

Comment: BSONWriter is invariant, having `BSONWriter[T]` doesn't mean you have `BSONWriter[U <: T]`. Either expose `Done` as `ProcessingStatus`, or really use enumeratum that provide BSON support for such case.

Comment: what do you mean by "expose ```Done``` as ```ProcessingStatus```"? also tried to use enumeratum support ```implicit val reader: BSONReader[ProcessingStatus] = implicitly[BSONReader[ProcessingStatus]]```, didn't solve it

Comment: You don't use enumeratum in example but override handler with objects. Please first have a look at enumeratum examples and doc.

Comment: if you could post code fix that should work it will be be awesome. I look in documentations and could not find what I need, or probably didn't understand something, this is why I'm here @cchantep